# In sublimemerge, how do you collapse the sidebar groups such as `tags` or `stashes`?

Tags: git, sublimemerge

When using sublimemerge with large repo's, the sidebar can get quite noisey.

Is there a way to collapse the sidebar groups?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of build 1070, this is now available - simply use the chevrons to the left of the stacks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is not (as of the time of this answer) a mechanism in place to allow for folding of the information that appears in the side bar or filtering parts of it away.

Comment: Thanks @OdatNurd - thought it might be a hidden setting somewhere.